# Replace parent scope with directive attribute controller scope

Tags: angularjs

I've had no success creating an Attribute directive that uses vm in the child elements and uses the directive controller scope and no it's parent scope.

See: http://fiddle.jshell.net/vzuf9psq/

How can I make the second message show the message from the directive controller?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use directive scope to transfer properties from one controller to another
2. Use bindToController to bind directive scope to controller (or much better, use Angular component's syntax).
3. Do not paste template inside directive tag (or use transclude for this purpose)

See [Final fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/s2sgLj36/1/)

Comment: Yeah using a template seems to fix the issue, I guess that if the directive adds no markup and there's no data binded (sometimes is not needed) the scope will never exist outside the controller.

Thanks!